# Using Cauchy Integral Formula to Solve $\int_\gamma (z-(4+4i))\sin(\frac{1}{z+(3-3i)})dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm trying to use Cauchy Integral Formula to find the value of the integral

$$\int_\gamma (z-(4+4i))\sin(\frac{1}{z+(3-3i)})dz$$

where $\gamma$ is the circle centered at the origin and with radius 7.

This is my proposed solution: We will start by naming $f(z) = (z-(4+4i))\sin(\frac{1}{z+(3-3i)})$, noticing that $f(z)$ has a simple pole  inside $\gamma$ and that both $\sin(z)$ and $f(z)$ are entire.

To solve this problem we will have to use Cauchy's Residue Theorem. First, we start by expressing $\sin(\frac{1}{z+(3-3i)})$ as a series, we known that the Taylor series for $\sin(z)$ is:

$$
\sin(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} (z)^{2n+1}
$$

Therefore we will have that:
$$
\sin(\frac{1}{z + (3-3i)}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \frac{1}{(z + (3-3i))^{2n+1}}
$$

We can also see that:
$$
(z-(4+4i)) = (z + (3 - 3i) - (3 - 3i) - (4 + 4i)) = [(z + (3 -3i)) - (7+i)]
$$

Now we can express $f(z)$ as:

$$
f(z) = [(z + (3 -3i)) - (7-i)]\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \frac{1}{(z + (3-3i))^{2n+1}}
$$

$$
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \frac{1}{(z + (3-3i))^{2n}} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\frac{-(7+i)}{(z + (3-3i))^{2n+1}}
$$

From this last equation its easy to see that:

$$Res(f(z), -(3-3i)) = -(7+i) $$

Now, using Cauchy Residue Theorem we have that

$$\int_\gamma (z-(4+4i))\sin(\frac{1}{z+(3-3i)})dz = -2\pi i(7+i) = (2 -14 i)\pi$$